# Cakephp 3 query OR Condition

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Guys how can I apply an OR condition in the following Where statement ?

```
$this->IbCommisions->find()->matching(
    'Users.Accounts',function ($q) {
        return $q->where(['IbCommisions.ib_id' => $this->userid, 'Users.country_id' => $this->request->data['country']]);
}
```

To become something like

```
(['IbCommisions.ib_id' => $this->userid OR 'Users.country_id' => $this->request->data['country']])
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
return $q->where(['OR' => [
    'IbCommisions.ib_id' => $this->userid,
    'Users.country_id' => $this->request->data['country']
]]);
```

or alternatively

```
return $q->where(['IbCommisions.ib_id' => $this->userid])
    ->orWhere(['Users.country_id' => $this->request->data['country']]);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions

Comment: For future reference, in the doc `orWhere` is deprecated. `As of 3.5.0 the orWhere() method is deprecated.This method creates hard to predict SQL based on the current query state. Use where() instead as it has more predictable and easier to understand behavior.`